App crashes when trying to animate fontSize in MotionScene for Compose
I'm using version 1.0.1 of Motion Layout for Jetpack Compose alongside with compose bom 2024.02.01, material3 and a JSON5 motion scene, and when i try to do a simple use case such animating Text() font size, the app crashes with the next error message:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no paragraph androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.TextStringSimpleNode.draw(TextStringSimpleNode.kt:390)
I followed the example in: https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Compose-MotionLayout-JSON-Syntax
    custom: {
    background: '#0000FF',
    textColor: '#FFFFFF',
    textSize: 12
    }
    
    var properties = motionProperties("a")
    Text(text = "Hello", modifier = Modifier
    .layoutId(properties.value.id())
    .background(properties.value.color("background"))
    ,color = properties.value.color("textColor")
    ,fontSize = properties.value.fontSize("textSize")
    )


I think it has something to do with the implementation of the new Modifier.Node() method for Text composables drawing/rendering
I have tried to decrease and increase progress and motionLayout height, it did not work

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308501489

To change font size with animation in Jetpack Compose, simply do this:

    val size = animateIntAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected)
            12
        else
            18,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 50, delayMillis = 0, easing = LinearEasing), label = ""
    )
    
Text(text = "Your Text", fontSize = size.value.sp)


you can change isSelected, that is just a sample to show how to change value.
